# Склонение слов "бриджи" и "капри"

Tags: заимствования, склонение

Я про брюки. Почему слово "бриджи" склоняется, а "капри" нет?

Comment: Как вы себе представляеете ответ на вопрос, начинающийся с "почему"?
"Потому что это так"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово *бриджи* у нас ассоциируется со словом *брюки*, которое склоняется легко, как многие другие "парные" существительные. Потому и *бриджи* склоняем, по аналогии. 
А на неизменяемость слова "капри" повлияло, мне кажется, очень часто употребляемое название острова Капри, которое является несклоняемым именем  существительным. Считается, что в конце 40-х именно на Капри впервые появились такие брюки.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, это всё потому, что склоняемые "бриджи" вполне благозвучны в русском языке, а "капри" - нет.